# Know if input is in use and disable the hotkey (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use some **hotkeys** on my website, but when the user is inside the search form or inside comment. I want to disable them.

What the best for me to do it? Thanks

Example of my hotkey:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e)
{
    if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 74) // next post
    { 
        return scroll('next');
    }

    if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 75) // prev post
    { 
        return scroll('prev');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the `event.target` element. If that element is from type `INPUT` you might want to omit the handler code. Could look like

```
$(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if( e.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT' ) {
            if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 74) // next post
            { 
                return scroll('next');
            }

            if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 75) // prev post
            { 
                return scroll('prev');
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if `e.target.nodeName === INPUT` (the event is triggered inside an input field) and act accordingly